# How to limit Tab listener to callback only if the textbox has change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a Tab key listener for a textbox.

```
$('#mytextbox').live('keydown', function (e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 9 || e.which == 9) {
      // TO DO SOMETHING
   }
});
```

However, for some reason I need to limit the tab listener's callback to invoke only when the textbox has **changed**. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to check the value of the input field to make sure it's different from it's original value?

E.g.

```
$('#mytextbox').live('keydown', function (e) {
   if ((e.keyCode == 9 || e.which == 9) && ($('#TextBox').val() != 'Starting Value')) {
      // TO DO SOMETHING
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just like:

```
var data = "";
$('#mytextbox').live('keydown', function (e){
    if(e.which == 9 || e.keyCode == 9){
         if($(this).val() != data){
             alert('changed!');
             data = $(this).val();
         }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DDCZS/1/

Answer (score 0):

Or without storing / knowing value of that textbox:

```
var changed = false;

$('#mytextbox').on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 9 && changed) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // TO DO SOMETHING
        alert("works");
        changed = false;
    } else {
        changed = true;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9a37b/